# Using Rasch estimates in models

Tags: model, rasch

I am just starting to learn about Rasch analysis, but there is something I am a little confused on. So let's say you conduct an analysis using a rating scale model for some Likert scale and everything looks good. When you want to use that scale for a study, let's say as a predictor variable, can you just put the Rasch estimates into a standard regression?

Meaning, would you just put the Rasch estimates in logits as the predictor in a standard regression. Or are you then limited to a Rasch regression? Relatedly, does it make sense to use the raw scores from the scale, summed or averaged, if in the Rasch analysis there appear to be equal sized thresholds?

I understand the scale creation aspect of Rasch analysis, like under the rating scale model, but I am confused as to how to use the estimates for modeling some DV.

Comment: Rasch analysis is the use of a [Rasch model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasch_model)?

Comment: Could you give us more details on how exactly would you like to use them? What is your data? What is the research question? Yes, you can use them as features, but I don't get the part about averaging them?

Comment: I don't have a specific dataset that I am trying to use it on. The question is conceptual. But for clarification, does some 10 item scale (X) predict outcome Y. Since the scale will be in logits, can you just put that into a regression? Or do you HAVE to use Rasch regression, latent regression, etc.? Relatedly, if when doing the Rasch analysis in the rating scale model you find that all items have equal thresholds, would it then be reasonable to sum the items, and then do the standard thing of summing the items (or averaging) and then that is X, as opposed to it being in logits.